# Firebase In-App Messaging, Test on Device not show up on real device

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am starting to utilize the In-app messaging feature of firebase.

I didn't create a real campaign yet, but only use the the [Test on Device] when creating one.
So this issue is not related with in-production campaign, but [Test on Device] feature.

The message does not show up on a physical device, but showed on a simulator.

I could not move forward since our application is already in production, and I need to confirm the result before put a real campaign online.

My env/condition is following:

1. Firebase version is 9.0.0
2. Analytics is installed
3. Installation IDs are correctly filled, as I could confirm the message in simulator.
4. in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?authuser=0&hl=en&platform=ios), it said we should confirm the message

> [Firebase/InAppMessaging][I-IAM180017] Seeing test message in fetch response. Turn the current instance into a testing instance.

But there is no such log in the console.

So anyone succeeded test the message on the real device, please share your experience.

Comment: Do you absolutely see nothing on the device or console after the Test Campaign is sent? If that is the case - my experience has been that it was because of incorrect FIDs. I forgot to add my real device's FID in the Test Campaign wizard and it still had my emulator's FID. Worked after adding the real device's FID.

Comment: Currently got the same issue, did you solved it ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're facing a similar issue. While the in-app messaging document and the previous answer suggest checking specific logs, you might encounter a log message indicating the need to enable the `Firebase In-App Messaging` API instead.

To resolve this, follow these steps:

1. Open the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
2. Navigate to your project by clicking on the project dropdown at the top of the page.
3. In the sidebar, click on "APIs & Services" > "Library."
4. In the search bar, type "Firebase In-App Messaging API" and select it from the results.
5. Click the "Enable" button to activate the API for your project.

Alternatively, you can directly enable the API for your project using this URL: [Enable Firebase In-App Messaging API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firebaseinappmessaging.googleapis.com/overview?project=your_projectID).

After enabling the API, don't forget to refresh your app and test if the issue is resolved.

Please replace `"your_projectID"` with the actual ID of your project before posting this answer.

Also, you have the exact URL in firebase log

Comment: life saver, works after enabling it from cloud console